# How to generate dynamic textboxes and label using numericUpDown1 in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I can dynamically create textboxes and labels using numericUpDown1, but i cannot decrement when the user wants to decrease the number of textboxes and labels to be used.

Here is my code :

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
Point p = new Point(35, 40 * i);
textbox.Location = p;

textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(219, 20);
textbox.Name = "txtbox_" + i;
textbox.Text = "txtbox_" + i;
gb_addPos.Controls.Add(textbox);


Label label = new Label();
Point q = new Point(5, 40 * i);
label.Location = q;

label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 15);
textbox.Name = "label_" + i;
label.Text = i + ".)";
gb_addPos.Controls.Add(label);
i++;

Size r = new Size(259, 50 * j);
gb_addPos.Size = r;
j++;
```

Thank you for giving time in helping a beginner like me..
Very much Appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like dynamically adding and removing only by the name of the control.
What I like to do is manage the list of controls myself and call `Add` or `Remove` with the actual control:

```
private readonly List<TextBox> _txts = new List<TextBox>();

// Then you can add a textbox with:
TextBox txt = // init a new textbox
this._txts.Add(txt);
this.Controls.Add(txt);

// And remove with:
this.Controls.Remove(this._txts[i]);
this._txts.RemoveAt(i);
```

The reason I like this approach specifically is because it doesn't force you to unbox `Control` into a `TextBox` if you want to treat it like what it really is.
But the greater reason is that you actually manage the your array `TextBox`s on your own. What if you had a `TextBox` that wasn't dynamically created? That would mess things up.

```
// looping over textboxes:
foreach (var txt in this._txts)
{
    // txt is TextBox
    // With the normal approach you would have to write:
    // foreach (var txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gb_addPos.Controls.remove("txtbox_" + I);

Comment: Sir @fernan, how do i do it if it is inside a method of numericUpDown1.ValueChanged? Do i do if and else statement?

Comment: Firstly I don't know what type of control 'numericUpDown1' is but obviously is a control which allows you to get numerical choices?

Comment: Inside ValueChanged you firstly retrieve the value and append it to 'txtbox' to get the name of the textbox you want removed. Then you can iterate gb_addPos with foreach (Control ctr in gb_addPos.Controls)
{
    if(ctr is Textbox|| ctr.Name = selectedTextboxName)
    {
       gb_addPos.Controls.remove(selectedTextboxName);    }              
}